# How do I configure VSCode Intellisense for TypeScript to display properties only?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an API which uses parameter objects and the only way to stay sane is to have intellisense.

It works to an extent, but this is annoying.

[image: a list of stuff i don't want]

None the less, I see that the list does contain properties i want. How can I make this list only show my properties of the object, and not the kitchen sink?

[image: i want just these in the list]

If it isn't too clear, then basically,  I don't want to cycle through a massive list of stuff, looking for `analytics`, I don't want to right click and go into this method searching what is available, and I don't want to seek docs either. I just want the "properties" of an object to take priority.

Comment: Those suggestions don't seem to be from VS Code's standard js/ts language features. Do you have an auto import plugin installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These suggestions are coming from the [auto import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) extension and not VS Code's standard JavaScript and TypeScript language features. You can tell this by the `[AI]` in the suggestion item label

VS Code has supported auto imports out of the box [since 1.18](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_auto-import-for-javascript-and-typescript) so this extension should no longer be required. If the built-in auto imports aren't working properly, please [file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose)

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, уou can also control your Intellisense preferences in `Settings>Text Editor>Suggestions` page:

[image: vs code text editor display properties suggestions hide words]

Answer (score 0):

These days, it seems like at least the one you want is promoted to the top of the list.  `Ctrl+Space` once you've typed `{` will show the object properties at the top of the autocomplete list.